# What is the meaning of "spec'd" in "That will ensure that the input is not driven to a non spec'd value"?

Tags: word-meaning, contractions, verbing

Somebody was teaching me electronics over the internet. I don't know if he is a native English speaker or not.

> He said: "To see more realistic effects, try using a clamping diode from the non inverting input to ground. That will ensure that the input is not driven to a non spec'd value which would actually blow out a real chip".

What is the meaning of the word "spec'd" ?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but probably it is "non-specified".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Spec** is shorthand for **specifications** which are written descriptions for how an instrument or piece of equipment is used.  In your example, a **non spec'd value** is a value which falls **outside** the **normal operating range** as described in its specification.

If the value is **too high** the chip will **burn out**, or the equipment **will fail**.

Comment: In this case "Spec'd" comes from "specified", to mean "as written in the specification" .

Answer (score 14):

The word spec is often used in place of specifications, and [spec'd](https://goo.gl/OgOeow) is sometimes used to mean, "to provide specifications for", essentially, *specified*.

From the context you provided, it appears to be referring to the input voltage exceeding that for which a real "chip" would be rated.